# Xaringan: How do you change code chunk background color?

Tags: xaringan

Is it possible to change the background color--and other attributes--of code chunks? Is there a class associated with code chunks?

Modifying the background color for inline code is simple:

```
.remark-inline-code{
  background-color: #000000
}
```

But I am unable to find an equivalent specifically for code chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the div using Chrome developer tools, you see that the color is set by class `.hljs-github .hljs`.

Setting

```
.hljs-github .hljs {
    background: red;
}
```

should do what you want :)