# xaringan: Changing code background for specific chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

In [this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1333) feature request back in 2016 Yihui shows, at the bottom, how to have different code chunks have different backgrounds in R Markdown. I've attached a screenshot of this here. Is there a way to do this with xaringan?

[image: rmd-solution]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030224/xaringan-how-do-you-change-code-chunk-background-color) answer, which works for changing the background color for all code chunks, but I can't figure out how to modify the css so I can change the background for just a few specific chunks.

The goal here is to have most chunks show up normally, but a few show up with a red background or similar to signify "This is bad". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was actually something I was trying to [work out a few days ago](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/169).

Here's one workaround. 
First in your css file or either place the following in `xaringan` Rmarkdown file:

````
```{css, echo=F}
.code-bg-red .remark-code, .code-bg-red .remark-code * {
 background-color:red!important;
}
```
````

and then wrap the code chunk like

````
.code-bg-red[
```{r}
lm(speed ~ dist, cars)
```
]
````

then your output will be: 
[image: red chunk output]

You can, of course, change the red to other colors to suit your needs.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks Emi! I actually almost just messaged you on Twitter because I figured you’d know! You’re amazing!